# I can not uninstall a package

Tags: pip, uninstallation

I installed the PyPDF2 package using.

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

I want to uninstall it, but it does not work.

```
pip uninstall PyPDF2
```

In the 'Console 1/A' the square button is red, and it seems like running (you can check the image below).

[Console 1/A image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SMxi.png)

After running the uninstall command, it happens that it doesn't work anymore, so I have to close anaconda and start from the beginning again.

Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: Are you running `pip uninstall PyPDF2` from the IPython terminal? You need to execute it from a regular terminal

Comment: @cellularegg I am running it in the terminal provided in Spyder (IPython console). But for instance, when I do ```pip install PyPDF2``` I did not have that problem.

Comment: Is there any error message? If yes please update your answer.

Comment: @cellularegg no, I don't get any error message